# Trouble with Launching FM app

Tags: android

I am trying to Build an app which starts the FM radio on a shake.and changes the channel accordingly with shake. With the help of Google I came to know that there is only vendor specific API for this I mean to access FM

Any way I decided to go with my mission. With this I am having few problem.

1) How can I get this API I mean I want API for samsung and HTC.
2) Can I access device FM or I have to create a new one?

Somebody please help me with this